# TSQL [CONVERT] does not work for MS Access

Tags: c#, t-sql, ms-access

I've written a program in C# that exports Access DB to Excel. In my SQL query i'm using the CONVERT function to change an integer to string but Access does not have CONVERT so my program is throwing an error message.

Is there a possible way to run the following query in MS Access?

```
SELECT
'<b>Manufacturer</b>:<br>' + Manufacturer + '<br><br>Dimensions:<br>' + CONVERT(varchar(50),H) + 'H x ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),W) + 'W x ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),D) + 'D' as Summary,
  FROM Inventory
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access will convert the numeric fields on its own, but you do need to use `&` instead of `+`:

```
SELECT '<b>Manufacturer</b>:<br>' & Manufacturer & '<br><br>Dimensions:<br>' & H & 'H x ' & W & 'W x ' & D + 'D' as Summary
FROM Inventory
```